# Will proxies cache HTTP Responses when authentication is provided?

Tags: http, caching, credentials

Given a URI which has headers for caching properly configured.

If two users make a request to the same URI but provide two different sets of credentials, will a proxy cache the response per user+URI, or per URI, or not at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The response will only be used for other users if the `Cache-Control` response header contains the `public` directive. Apart from that, the proxy must not cache a response to an authorized request.

Read the [section Authorization of the HTTP 1.1 standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8) for all the details.

Comment: This is a subtly simple, yet extremely helpful answer and question.